# Zuul not forwarding requests to other micro-services

Tags: java, spring-boot, ipc, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I am using spring boot micro-services. I have configured eureka, zuul proxy and another microservice(account). If I am calling from account directly it is working fine. account and zuul server both showing on eureka.

When I try to hit using zuul proxy it is getting status code `200OK` but not getting any result

Below is my configuration for zuul

### Zuul.yml

```
server:
  port: 8076
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8078/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
    health-check-url-path: /actuator/health
    status-page-url-path: /actuator/info
logging:
  level:
    com.netflix.discovery: 'ON'
    org.springframework.cloud: DEBUG
zuul:
  ignoredServices: '*'
  routes:
    account:
      serviceId: ACCOUNT
      url: http://192.168.0.62:8081/
      stripPrefix: false
      predicate:
      - Path=/accounts/**
  debug:
    requests: true
management:
  security:
    enabled: false
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
```

**Console log so far**

> route matched=ZuulRoute{id='account', path='/account/**',
>   serviceId='ACCOUNT', url='http://192.168.0.62:8081/',
>   stripPrefix=false, retryable=null, sensitiveHeaders=[],
>   customSensitiveHeaders=false, }
>   --------------------------- Mapped to org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController@7bb67520

### log of actuator/env

```
"zuul.ignoredServices": {
"value": "*"
},
"zuul.routes.account.serviceId": {
"value": "ACCOUNT"
},
"zuul.routes.account.url": {
"value": "http://192.168.0.62:8081/"
},
"zuul.routes.account.stripPrefix": {
"value": false
},
"zuul.routes.account.predicate[0]": {
"value": "Path=/accounts/**"
},
"zuul.debug.requests": {
"value": true
},
"management.security.enabled": {
"value": false
},
"management.endpoints.web.exposure.include": {
"value": "*"
}
```

I am unable to get anything from here if something is mising, Kindly check and do let me know. any help will be useful

thanks.

If needed more info let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, you set up Eureka but you're not using it correctly. First in zuul yaml you have

```
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
```

you don't need to register your zuul application with eureka, because you are accessing zuul gateway directly, no one service will try to locate and reach your gateway.

Then

```
account:
  serviceId: ACCOUNT
  url: http://192.168.0.62:8081/
  stripPrefix: false
  predicate:
  - Path=/accounts/**
```

if you have service discovery you don't need `url` property and `predicate: - Path`, try:

```
account:
  serviceId: <YOUR_ACCOUNT_SERVICE_ID>
  stripPrefix: false
  path: /account/**
```

by default serviceId is:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: <YOUR_ACCOUNT_SERVICE_ID>
```

check my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55616882/5953575)