# How to forward to different path using netflix zuul?

Tags: reverse-proxy, http-proxy, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm using netflix zuul embedded in a spring boot 1.5.x application.
Behind zuul are some microservices. These microservices expose public endpoints under /public/** .

Now i want to expose these public endpoints via zuul api gateway but stripping the "/public" out of the final api gateway url.

Example (expected) from outside (request through zuul api gateway):

```
api.yourdomain.tld/path/to/service/endpoint
```

Zuul should forward this request to (with **/public** in the url):

```
service:{port}/public/path/to/service/endpoint
```

How can i achieve this **without using url parameter** in the zuul configuration. I would like to rely on the internal client side load balancing using **serviceId** parameters. I couldn't figure it out.

If this isn't a good pattern, should i split my microservices into webservices and core-services? So that only webservices are mounted/accessible via Zuul?

This configuration works fine but it uses the url parameter instead of serviceId:

```
    custom-service:
      path: /path/to/service/endpoint/**
      stripPrefix: false
      url: http://custom-service:51022/public
      sensitiveHeaders:
```

Answer (score 3):

You need service discovery via Spring Cloud Netflix [Eureka](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka) , check [Introduction](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka) and [How to declare routes with serviceId](https://springbootdev.com/2018/02/03/microservices-declare-zuul-routes-with-eureka-serviceid-spring-cloud-zuul-eureka/)

After setting that up, enable zuul proxy and discovery client in zuul application

```
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class ZuulProxyApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(ZuulProxyApplication.class, args);
   }
}
```

than:

```
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true
```

Zuul application don't need to be registered with Eureka, and it should fetch the registry.

And than you can say:

```
zuul:
  routes:
    custom-service:
      path: /path/to/service/endpoint/**
      stripPrefix: false
      serviceId: customServiceId
```

If you want to have defined multiple routes for one service, do:

```
zuul:
  routes:
    custom-service:
      path: /path/to/service/endpoint/**
      stripPrefix: false
      serviceId: customServiceId
    custom-service:
      path: /second_path/to/service/endpoint/**
      stripPrefix: false
      serviceId: customServiceId
```

Comment: how to do the same configuration using application.properties